# How to Extract Confidence in GoCV

Tags: python, opencv, go

I Try to Remake the Python ver Mask Detector with Golang, and i get stuck at "Extract Confidence" with GoCV, the python code it said like this

```
detections = net.forward()

# loop over the detections
for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with
    # the detection
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
```

it's work fine on python, but how i can get confidence value with GoCV ?

here is my current work

```
    currPath := "/media/fz/Project (Running)/Unknown/TryDetectMask/face_detector"
    prototxtPath := path.Join(currPath, "deploy.prototxt")
    weightsPath := path.Join(currPath, "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel")
    //definedConfidence := 0.5
    //modelPath := "mask_detector.model"

    net := gocv.ReadNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

    //model, _ := tf.LoadSavedModel(modelPath, []string{"serve"}, nil)
    img := gocv.IMRead("/home/fz/Desktop/download.jpeg", gocv.IMReadUnchanged)

    //orig := img.CopyTo
    //imgSize := img.Size()

    img.ConvertTo(&img, gocv.MatTypeCV32F)
    imgBlob := gocv.BlobFromImage(img, 1.0, image.Point{X: 300, Y: 300}, gocv.NewScalar(104.0, 177.0, 123.0, 0), false, false)

    net.SetInput(imgBlob, "")
    detections := net.Forward("")

    //a, _ := detections.FromPtr(1,1,gocv.MatTypeCV32F,1,2)
    fmt.Printf("%v", detections.Total())

    //detectionsMat := detections.Reshape(1,1)
    //_, maxVal, _, maxLoc := gocv.MinMaxLoc(detectionsMat)
    //
    //fmt.Println(maxVal)
    //fmt.Println(maxLoc.X)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Success doing this using this line of code

```
detections := net.Forward("")

for i := 0; i < detections.Total(); i += 7 {
    confidence := detections.GetFloatAt(0, i+2)
```